# How to set default homepage from another folder in .HTACCESS file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I created a site and make its URL seo friendly like **www.mywebsite.com/home**.
but actual homepage is in my **/SomeFolder/index.php** which is rewrite its url to /home.
Now i want to set **/home** url as a default page in htaccess file. But when i set this.

```
DirectoryIndex /home
```

I got the 500 error. One way is to give the redirection in index.php so it will redirect me to the /home page. but i think its a weird method.
Is there any other way??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove that `DirectoryIndex` line.

You'll need this rule in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home/?$ /SomeFolder/index.php [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

this best article for create pretty URLs :
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls/

Answer (score 0):

Try `DirectoryIndex home/index.php`

Answer (score 0):

use this one , hope this will helpful for you

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule home(.*)\$ index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/somefolder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /somefolder/$1 [L]
```

src: https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_change_my_document_root_folder_using_an_htaccess_file/

Although I have entered an issue so I have an open question, which might be worth monitoring. I will update if I figure it out myself which I aim to do.

[.htaccess make sub dir home dir but force www and https whilst maintaining links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67956979/htaccess-make-sub-dir-home-dir-but-force-www-and-https-whilst-maintaining-links)